# APK upload failed for Alpha version. Errors from apksigner: Digest algorithm and Signature Algorithm Which is not supported on API levels [[16, 17]]

Tags: android, cordova, jarsigner

I had signed the APK by using keytool, jarsigner, and zipalign utlities.

I have used the following commands:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myAppTransporterKey.keystore -alias myTransporter -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console

cordova build --release android

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\myAppKey.keystore C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk myTransporter


jarsigner -verify C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk
```

After running:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk
```

getting this message: jar verified

After running:

```
zipalign -v 4 C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\myTransporter-Final.apk
```

get the message: Verification succesful

**After uploading to ALPAH in Google play console** I am getting following error

> Upload new APK to Alpha
>
> Uploading
>
> You have uploaded an APK with an invalid signature ( read more about
>   signing ). Errors from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer D2DTRANS.RSA): JAR
>   signature META-INF / D2DTRANS.RSA uses digest algorithm
>   2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 and Signature Algorithm 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 Which is not supported on API levels [[16, 17]]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need these stepps  :

1) jarsigner -verbose **-sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1** -keystore C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\myAppKey.keystore C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk myTransporter

2) jarsigner -verify C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk

3)  zipalign -v 4 C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\myTransporter-Final.apk

Hope this will help you ^^

Comment: Its woking...Thanks

Comment: You, sir, are a life a savor.

Comment: your welcom guys ^^ 
type it as the good respond for fast finding by other men who will need it .
have a nice day of coding x)

Comment: Yes, @AbdulRashid, you should mark this as the correct answer.  Worked for me, too!

Comment: jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: myTransporter.  myTransporter must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain - What does that mean please help

Comment: not working.. `ERROR: JAR signer HELLO.RSA: JAR signature META-INF/HELLO.RSA uses digest
algorithm 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 and signature algorithm 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 wh
ich is not supported on API Levels [[16, 17]]`

Comment: Hi men sry for late but for further asker u will need to focus api  level 26 as min api level ^^

Answer (score 1):

**You need these steps:**

```
zipalign -v 4 C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned-aligned.apk

apksigner sign --ks C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\myAppKey.keystore --ks-pass pass:[PASSWORD] --key-pass pass:[PASSWORD] --out C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-singned.apk C:\Users\ali\Documents\transporterApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

To sign applications use the BuildTools 24.0.3

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html

Comment: stackoverflow is a platform meant to be in English, so people with different native languages can communicate with each other. Please ask and answer in English. See: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-manually), you can perform the following steps:

1. generate the `.apk` file
2. Align data: `zipalign -v -p 4 my-app-unsigned.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk`
3. Sign the APK: `apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --out my-app-release.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk`

You may need to define the type of the keystore with the `--ks-type` option:

```
~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/apksigner sign --ks-type pkcs12 --ks ~/[…].p12 \
--out android-release-signed-aligned.apk android-release-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in ***apksigner 0.8*** which was released in ***Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2***.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63525618) they will re-open to examine.