# Errors from apksigner: digest algorithm 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 and signature algorithm 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1

Tags: java, android, algorithm, apk, signature

Today when I try to upload a new version of my apk to Google Play, I have the following message:

> You loaded an APK with a signature that is not valid (get more information about the signatures) apksigner error: ERROR (Jar signer LEMON.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/LEMON.RSA uses digest algorithm 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 and signature algorithm 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 which is not supported on API Levels [[15, 17]]

The apk was compiled with Corona SDK, and earlier versions I had no problems with the same keystore.

What should I do to compile each time the app does not have to alter the apk with jarsigner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APK upload failed for Alpha version. Errors from apksigner: Digest algorithm and Signature Algorithm Which is not supported on API levels \[\[16, 17\]\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44874386/apk-upload-failed-for-alpha-version-errors-from-apksigner-digest-algorithm-and)

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this too, and the 'dupe question' part didn't help because we're both with corona. Here's what looks to be a solution: install java 1.6 sdk, instead of 1.8

https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/69279-suddenly-unable-to-build-for-android-due-to-keystore-issue/